# Alter Table in Polybase

Tags: polybase

When I created an External Table and point to a Hadoop HDF, I forgot to add a Reject in the script.  Getting error when Alter Table with Reject limit to 100,

ALTER TABLE ad_doc_actg REJECT LIMIT 100;

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'REJECT'.

Is Alter External Table allow in SQL Server 2017 Polybase?

Answer (score 0):

The feature "ALTER TABLE" is not supported with external tables even in SQL 2019